# How to text value from a textbox in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="TEST" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfreturn "So your name is #name#?")>
</cffunction>

<cfif (isDefined("form.test"))>
<cfoutput>#test()#</cfoutput><br>
</cfif>

<cfform>
<cfinput name="names" type="text">
<cfinput name="TEST" type="submit" value="Call test()">
</cfform>
```

How to get the text from the textbox and set it in a variable?
THANKS!

Comment: Your form field is called 'names'.  So you just need to do `<cfset name = form.names>` inside your IF statement that you already have.

Comment: You you perhaps post your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as there are a number of issues with it (of course this could be a very pared down example,and not actually your code: it's hard to tell).

Comment: You would want to pass the value of of `name` to the function. Doing it the way you have breaks encapsulation. Functions should rarely reach outside of themselves for data. Any data it needs should be passed in as arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I would re-write this. Please note that I removed `cfform` and `cfinput` form example. They are not needed, and will likely cause issues down the road. You should pass in, as arguments, any data your function is going to need.

```
<cffunction name="test" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfreturn "So, your name is #arguments.name#?" />
</cffunction>

<cfif isDefined("form.name") >
    <cfoutput>#test( htmlEditFormat( form.name ) )#</cfoutput><br>
</cfif>

<form method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="TEST" type="submit" value="Call test()">
</form>
```

Comment: Um, no HTML encoding? :(

Comment: I would avoid htmleditformat. As of CF 11 it is no longer recommended, https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/HTMLEditFormat

Comment: On the contrary James, I would stick with HtmlEditFormat (or custom encoding) and _avoid encodeForHtml_ until the bugs have been fixed.

Comment: Since CF11 has not yet been released, the use of `htmlEditFormat()` is justified.

Comment: @PeterBoughton what *encodeForHtml* bugs were you speaking of back in 2014? Are they fixed? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to pass the correct form field name to fix this issue. In form fieldname `<cfinput name="names" type="text">` and the return variable name `<cfreturn "So your name is #names#?">` is not same. And unwanted closebracket "**)**" is there. So, If we correct the code means the issue will be fixed.

```
<cffunction name="TEST" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfreturn "So your name is #names#?")>
</cffunction>

<cfif (isDefined("form.test"))>
<cfoutput>#test()#</cfoutput><br>
</cfif>

<cfform>
<cfinput name="names" type="text">
<cfinput name="TEST" type="submit" value="Call test()">
</cfform>
```

This fix answer may help you!